# To check whether the file is empty

Tags: powershell

I need to check whether the file `"file.txt"` is empty or not in both PowerShell version 2.0 and 5.0. The problem I face here is the command lets used in PowerShell 5.0 doesn't work in PowerShell 2.0

`(Get-Content -Path .\file.txt).length -eq $Null)` - Returns false even though the file is empty in PowerShell 5.0 but in PowerShell 2.0 it returns true.

`(Get-Content -Path .\file.txt).length -eq 0)` - Returns true in PowerShell 5.0 but in PowerShell 2.0 it returns false

Is there any solution to the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that I wrote to check this.

It uses .NET to read all text and there's also a match `\S` which matches for anything but a space that basically ignores any whitespaces and searches for everything else.

This means that the file can have whitespaces in it and this function will return `$true` as it doesn't contain any text.

The reason for using `[IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file)` is that in my testing it's around 10 times faster than the `Get-Content` when reading 100k lines.

If performance is an issue then this is the one I'd use otherwise use the `Get-Content` method code at the bottom.

### `.NET` method:

```
$fileToCheck = "$PSScriptRoot\Test-FileEmpty.ps1"

Function Test-FileEmpty {

  Param ([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$file)

  if ((Test-Path -LiteralPath $file) -and !(([IO.File]::ReadAllText($file)) -match '\S')) {return $true} else {return $false}

}

Test-FileEmpty $fileToCheck
```

### `Get-Content` method:

```
$fileToCheck = "$PSScriptRoot\Test-FileEmpty.ps1"

Function Test-FileEmpty {

  Param ([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$file)

  if ((Test-Path -LiteralPath $file) -and !((Get-Content -LiteralPath $file -Raw) -match '\S')) {return $true} else {return $false}

}

Test-FileEmpty $fileToCheck
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe just this should work.

```
if (Get-Content .\File.txt){$true}else{$false}
```

In PS 2.0, I don't think `(Get-Content -Path .\file.txt).Length` would return anything. You would have to use `Get-Content -Path .\file.txt | select -ExpandProperty Length`.

But for your purposes, you don't even need to look at the `length` of the file, just the content.

Comment: the solution stills gives $false even though the file is empty

Comment: That is correct. the expected behavior is to return `True` only when the file is NOT empty. Wouldn't that work for you? If not, you can always do this. `if (!(Get-Content .\File.txt)){$true}else{$false}`

Comment: the second solution gives desired output

Comment: if u look at it objectively, It doesnt really matter which gives true and which gives false. You can just build ur logic around that. the second solution is completely for the sake of Aesthetics.